# IIS/ASP.NET - Infinite redirects in deployed code

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, redirect, iis

I am getting an infinite redirect loop only when I deploy my code to a Production environment.  I am attempting to force SSL on the page by using a simple code redirect.  I am running into the issue with a stripped-down old school web form (I'm stuck on .NET 3.5 for this project).  All code is below.
Any ideas on why I would get an infinite redirect look in Production and not Test?
Notes on test vs production:

- Test is IIS 10 on Windows 10.
- Production is IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003 R2.
- Test uses a self-signed SSL cert.
- Production uses a fully trusted SSL cert.
- Identical web.configs

ASPX Markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SecurePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="wwwroot.SecurePage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            This page is secure!
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CODE-BEHIND:

```
namespace wwwroot
{
    public partial class SecurePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith("https://"))
                Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace("http://", "https://"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `!`

Comment: Is `https` activated in IIS?

Comment: It is.  In fact, I should mention I can hit static resources with the `https` scheme without issue.

Comment: If you have a load balancer (e.g. IIS `ARR`), I would suspect that your application _may_ be receiving `http` from it. Your code is similar to a check `Request.IsSecureConnection` which will _always_ be `false` in such a case, thereby causing the infinite loop. Essentially client -> load balancer is `https`, then from load balancer -> web farm it's `http`. Hth.

Comment: Hmm..by "static resources" do you mean resources not handled by your application (not ASP.net pipeline) like images?

Comment: @EdSF, there IS INDEED a load balancer in the equation. I had tried `Request.IsSecureConnection` at first and got the infinite redirect, with the same results (as you mentioned).  Any chance you know how to circumvent this?

Comment: @EdSF, yes, that's exactly what I mean.  CSS files, JS files, Images, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a load balancer (e.g. `IIS ARR`), I would suspect that your application may be receiving `http` from it. Your code is similar to a check `Request.IsSecureConnection` which will **always** be *false* in such a case, thereby causing the infinite loop. Essentially client -> load balancer is `https`, then from load balancer -> web farm it's `http`

> ...there IS INDEED a load balancer in the equation. I had tried Request.IsSecureConnection at first and got the infinite redirect...I can hit static resources with the https scheme without issue, CSS files, JS files, Images, etc.

Your load balancer will *typically (hopefully)* have a header that indicates such. You should handle it at the IIS level with a [rewrite rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) - *before* it hits the ASP.net pipeline (which is why/how static resources are "unaffected"). You'll have to remove code that checks for it too (don't check and redirect at the ASP.Net level).

Here's a sample I use for a specific provider (obviously you'll have to check with your provider):

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />

    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_CLUSTER_HTTPS}" pattern="^on$" negate="true" />
      <add input="{HTTP_CLUSTER_HTTPS}" pattern=".+" negate="true" />

    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{SCRIPT_NAME}/{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

Hth...

Comment: Thanks @EdSF.  That solves the immediate problem!  Now on to figuring out redirect rules...